# Acceder al método getUsuario() desde una vista en php

Tags: php, postgresql

Mi problema radica que no puedo acceder al método getUsuario() en la vista index2.php, el método se encuentra en la clase controlador.php y tiene la funcionalidad característica de un método getter; e incluido en la vista el archivo además de crear el correspondiente objeto de dicha clase y con el objeto trato de acceder al método pero no al imprimirlo este no lo hace.

Adjunto el código:

index2.php

```
<?php 


    include_once("controlador.php");

    include("control.php");

    $datos = new Controlador();

    echo $datos->getUsusario();

    session_start();

    if($_SESSION['usuario'] != true){
       header('Location:index.php');
    }

 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Logeado</title>
 </head>
 <header>
 <form method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="cerrarSesion">Cerrar la sesión</button>
</form>
</header>
<body>
   <h1>Bienvenido <?php $datos->getUsuario(); ?></h1>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controlador.php

```
<?php


 include_once("conexion.php");

 include_once("validar.php");

 include_once("validar-registro.php");

 class Controlador extends Conn
 {

  private $nombre;
  private $apellido;
  private $usuario;
  private $correo;
  private $contrasena;

  private $prueba;
  private $registro;
  private $conexion;


public function getNombre(){
    return $this->nombre;
}

public function setNombre($nombre){
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
}

public function getApellido(){
    return $this->apellido;
}
public function setApellido($apellido){
    $this->apellido = $apellido;
}

public function getUsuario(){
    return $this->usuario;
}

public function setUsuario($usuario){
    $this->usuario = $usuario;
}

public function getCorreo(){
    return $this->correo;
}

public function setCorreo($correo){
    $this->correo = $correo;
}

public function getContrasena(){
    return $this->constrasena;
}

public function setContrasena($constrasena){
    $this->constrasena = $constrasena;
}

public function __construct(){

    $this->prueba = new Validacion();

    $this->registro = new registro();

    $this->conexion = new Conn();

}

public function login(){

    if($this->prueba->Camponull($this->getUsuario()) || $this->prueba->Camponull($this->getContrasena)){

        $this->prueba->SendAction($this->getUsuario(),$this->getContrasena(), $correo = null);

        $count = $this->prueba->getCount();

        if($count){
            $this->prueba->CrearSesion();
        }else{
            $this->prueba->Errores($mensaje = "errorU");
        }

    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public function registro(){

    if($prueba->Camponull($this->getNombre()) || 
        $prueba->Camponull($this->getApellido()) ||
        $prueba->Camponull($this->getUsuario()) ||
        $prueba->Camponull($this->getCorreo()) ||
        $prueba->Camponull($this->getContrasena())){

            $prueba->SendAction($this->getUsuario(), $this->getContrasena(), $this->getCorreo());

            $count = $prueba->getCount();

            if($count){ 
                $prueba->Errores($mensaje = "usuarioE");
            }else{
                    if($registro->Nombre($this->getNombre()) && 
                        $registro->Apellido($this->getApellido()) &&
                        $registro->Usuario($this->getUsuario()) &&
                        $registro->Correo($this->getCorreo()) && 
                        $registro->Contrasena($this->getContrasena())){
                            $prueba->InsertUser($this->getNombre(), $this->getApellido(), $this->getUsuario(), $$this->getCorreo(), $this->getContrasena());
                            $prueba->CrearSesion();
                    }
            }
    }

}

public function cerrarSesion(){
    $this->prueba->cerrarSesion();
}
}



 ?>
```

Control.php

```
<?php 

 include_once("controlador.php");

 $Controlador = new Controlador();

 if(isset($_POST['inicio'])){
  $Controlador->setUsuario($_POST['username']);
  $Controlador->setContrasena($_POST['password']);
  $Controlador->login();
 }

 elseif(isset($_POST['registro'])){
  $Controlador->setNombre($_POST['nombre']);
  $Controlador->setApellido($_POST['apellido']);
  $Controlador->setUsuario($_POST['usuario']);
  $Controlador->setCorreo($_POST['correo']);
  $Controlador->setContrasena($_POST['contrasena']);

  $Controlador->registro();
 }

 elseif(isset($_POST['cerrarSesion'])){
   $Controlador->cerrarSesion();
 }
 ?>
```

index.php (Este es el que contiene el formulario), manda los datos por $_POST

```
<?php 

 include_once "control.php";

 session_start();

 if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']) && $_SESSION['usuario'] == true){
   header('Location:index2.php');
   exit();
 }

 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Login de prueba</title>

 <style>
    .error {
        border: solid 2px #FF0000;
    }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <h2>Login</h2>

 <form action="" method="POST">
    <label>Nombre de usuario:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" required="">
    <br>
    <label>Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" required="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="inicio" value="Ingresar">

 </form>



<h2>Registro</h2>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombres" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
        <br>
    <label>Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" required/>
        <br>
    <label>Nombre de usuario</label>    
        <input type="text" id="usuarios" name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de usuario"  required/>
        <br>
    <label>Correo</label>
        <input type="email" id="correos" name="correo"   placeholder="Correo"    required/>
        <br>
    <label>Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña" required/>     
        <br>

    <input type="submit" name="registro" value="registrar" />

</form>

<div id="mensaje"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="validacionFrontend.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por la atención brindada.

Comment: En tu codigo donde quieres imprimir el valor esta mal escrito usuario echo $datos->getUsusario(); Puedes revisar si ese es el problema

Comment: Pero ¿estás pasando datos en el POST? Pon un `var_dump($_POST);`  en alguna parte y comenta lo que muestra. Tienes dos condiciones para setear datos al objeto: `if(isset($_POST['inicio'])){` y  `elseif(isset($_POST['registro'])){`, debes comprobar si se están cumpliendo. Yo sólo veo un formulario con un botón. ¿Cómo estás mandando los datos?

Comment: Es cierto A. Cedano, por eso acabe de editar mi pregunta añadiendo el correspondiente index con su formulario.

Comment: ¿Sigue sin funcionar? Si no funciona dinos si has ido depurando tu código etapa por etapa ¿?  verificando que entra aquí por ejemplo: `if(isset($_POST['inicio'])){` y que los datos del POST llegan correctamente.

Comment: 'username' => string 'akjndkndajk' (length=11)
'password' => string 'kjdghgdk' (length=8)
'inicio' => string 'Ingresar' (length=8) (cuando le doy al botón ingresar).

Comment: Cuando genero el var_dump() del método getUsuario() no se muestra nada, ¿sabes porque pasa esto?

Comment: BIen, el código pasa el `isset`... sigue depurando: ¿depuraste después de los *setter*  cuál es el estado del objeto con `var_dump($Controlador);`? ... Luego hay una llamada al método `login` del controlador: `$Controlador->login();` ¿depuraste que está entrando ahí y que todo funciona bien en ese método?

Comment: Probe el valor en el var_dump($Controlador->login()); pero este no me arrojo ningun dato, ¿ que debería probar?

Comment: Si no sabes revisar el log de errores tienes que ir poniendo depuraciones en las diferentes etapas de tu código. Antes de llamar a `login` revisa el estado del objeto con un `var_dump($Controlador);`  después de los *setter*,  en la parte del `isset`

Comment: Hice otro var_dump() desde el archivo controlador.php con los métodos getUsuario() y getContrasena(), y estos me arrojaron lo siguiente:C:\wamp64\www\scrum\Actividades-master\loginScrum\controlador.php:75:string 'nouliet' (length=7)

C:\wamp64\www\scrum\Actividades-master\loginScrum\controlador.php:75:string '12345' (length=5) (Estos son los datos que envíe desde el formulario en el index.php)

Comment: Me perdí en tu último comentario. Estábamos aquí: `if(isset($_POST['inicio'])){
  $Controlador->setUsuario($_POST['username']);
  $Controlador->setContrasena($_POST['password']);
  $Controlador->login();
 }` es ahí donde debes probar el objeto, poniendo un `var_dump($Controlador);` antes de la llamada a login, y una vez hechos los *setter*, o sea, en la penúltima línea de ese bloque. ¿Me explico?

Comment: Si y perdona por eso, ya le hice el var_dump() al objeto $Controlador y me arrojó lo siguiente: private 'nombre' => null
  private 'apellido' => null
  private 'usuario' => string 'nouliet' (length=7)
  private 'correo' => null
  private 'contrasena' => string '12345' (length=5)
lo que significa que los datos si están llegando, ¿cuál es el siguiente paso?

Comment: Bueno sí, los datos le llegan, pero veo que haces una llamada a `login` y var_dump no indica que el objeto tenga un método `login` ¿o no pusiste el var_dump completo? Para que esto funcione: `$Controlador->login();` el objeto debe tener un método `login` el cual no veo en el resultado del `var_dump`

Comment: Pero el objeto es de la clase controlador.php y en el sí existe el método login, además que el login manda a los usuarios a la vista index2.php cuando el usuario ingresa correctamente los datos y en caso contrario, genera una salida o mejor dicho un echo

Comment: Hay que atenerse a la realidad. Si el var_dump muestra solamente eso es que ese objeto sólo tiene eso. Revisa los include y demás no sea que estés usando otro controlador o algo. Cuando haces `var_dump` de un objeto, te muestra sus valores, como el nombre, apellido pero también sus métodos.